# My Intent activity

Tags: android

I want to send two textview by intents. I am sending intents but I am not getting the desired result. I get two $12.99 as my output. Why doesn't it show the pizza name? Please help. I want to get my pizza name and then price in one line on my app. Here is my code:
XML

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/pizza1"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Mr. Meat Lover Pizza"
          android:textSize="25dp"
          android:textColor="#2c2349" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/price1"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
          android:text="$12.99+"
          android:textColor="#2c2349"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:paddingStart="15dp"
          android:textSize="25dp" />
<Button android:id="@+id/ckeckout1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price1"
        android:textColor="#2c2349"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff00"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout4"
              android:layout_below="@+id/layout3"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
              android:textSize="20dp"
              android:layout_width="230dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2"
              android:textSize="20dp"
              android:layout_width="130dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA

```
TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pizza1);
TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1);
```

My get intent is:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(SplPizzas.this, Cart.class);
String message1 = TextView1.getText().toString(); 
intent1.putExtra(Message1, message1);
String message2 = TextView2.getText().toString();
intent1.putExtra(Message2, message2);
startActivity(intent1);
break;
```

Activity 2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(SplPizzas.Message1);
String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(SplPizzas.Message2);
TextView output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
output1.setText(message1);
TextView output2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
output2.setText(message2);
```

Comment: You should format your code way better than this and secondly you can't send `TextViews` as Intents.

Answer (score 0):

@ferrari The way you wrote the code is bit terrible :P

I formatted it a bit and it runs on my end.

> As much I am able to guess I think you have mistakenly assigned same "String" to your SplPizzas.Message1 and SplPizzas.Message2.
>   
>  Thats why you are getting same value i.e. $12.99 in both cases.
>   
>  Please verify.

[image: Screen One]

[image: Screen Two - Cart]

Here is the code:

> MainActivity.java --> SplPizzas.java from your code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String MESSAGE1 = "msg1";
    public static String MESSAGE2 = "msg2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startNextActivity(View view){
       TextView TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pizza1);
       TextView TextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1);

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

        String message1 = TextView1.getText().toString();
        intent1.putExtra(MESSAGE1, message1);

        String message2 = TextView2.getText().toString();
        intent1.putExtra(MESSAGE2, message2);

        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```

> Main2Activity.java --> Cart.java from your code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MESSAGE1);
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MESSAGE2);

        TextView output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        output1.setText(message1);

        TextView output2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        output2.setText(message2);
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml --> First screen of your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.proged.mytempapp2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pizza1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mr. Meat Lover Pizza"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#2c2349"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$12.99+"
        android:textColor="#2c2349"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ckeckout1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price1"
        android:textColor="#2c2349"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff00"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:onClick="startNextActivity"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> activity_main2.xml --> Second screen of your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.proged.mytempapp2.Main2Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```